# How to implement modal bottom sheet with fab similar to flutter_speed_dial?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone tel me how to implement modal bottom sheet with fab similar to flutter_speed_dial (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_speed_dial). To show the bottom sheet instead of icons while fab is animated

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing it like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() {
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Flutter Bottom Sheet"),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text("Show Bottom Sheet"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          _showModalBottomSheet();
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _showModalBottomSheet() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Wrap(
          children: const [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.share),
              title: Text('Share'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.copy),
              title: Text('Copy Link'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
              title: Text('Edit'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]